# Adding counts based on flags by dates

Tags: sql

Could you please advise some direction on how to achieve the below format? I am at lost thinking solution for this problem. basically where flag is 0, sum it up and add it to the very next value where flag is 1 by date
date:

```
date         hrs_clock    some_flag    some_count
=================================================
6/20/2016    1            0            5
6/20/2016    2            0            6
6/20/2016    3            1            4
6/20/2016    4            1            2
6/20/2016    5            0            4
6/20/2016    6            0            6
6/21/2016    1            0            4
6/21/2016    2            0            3
6/21/2016    3            1            7
6/21/2016    4            1            2
6/21/2016    5            0            5
6/21/2016    6            0            4
6/22/2016    1            0            5
6/22/2016    2            0            5
6/22/2016    3            1            3
6/22/2016    4            1            2
6/22/2016    5            0            8
6/22/2016    6            0            4
```

Result:

```
date         hrs_clock    some_flag    some_count
=================================================
6/20/2016    3            1            15
6/20/2016    4            1             2
6/21/2016    3            1            24
6/21/2016    4            1             2
6/22/2016    3            1            22
6/22/2016    4            1             2
6/22/2016    5            0             8
6/22/2016    6            0             4
```

Comment: `...SUM(some_count) as ct GROUP BY date, hrsc_clock, some_flag` ?

Comment: You're going to need to include more explanation than just "help me make it look like this".

Comment: I'm not following the logic behind your expected resultset..

Comment: @Siyual ..basically where flag is 0, sum it up and add it to the very next value where flag is 1 by date

Comment: How do you have a single hrs_clock value then when it incorporates multiple different hrs_clock values? And why would you even include the 8 and 4 counts for 6/22 when they don't even meet the condition for having a flag of 1 follow them?  These results make little to no sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as this:

```
select 
    max(case when rn=1 then date else '1900-01-01' end) as date, 
    max(case when rn=1 then hrs_clock else -999 end) as hrs_clock, 
    max(some_flag) as some_flag, 
    sum(some_count) as some_count
from (
    select 
        *, row_number() over (
            partition by 
                case when flag_group=0 then date else flag_group end,
                case when flag_group=0 then hrs_clock else flag_group end
            order by date desc, hrs_clock desc
        ) [rn]
    from (
        select 
            *, 
            sum(cast(some_flag as int)) over (
                order by date desc, hrs_clock desc 
                rows unbounded preceding) [flag_group]        
        from log
    ) x
) xx
group by case when flag_group=0 then [date] else flag_group end,
         case when flag_group=0 then hrs_clock else flag_group end

order by date, hrs_clock
```